# passing parameter to shell script from html

Tags: html

whats the syntax to pass the parameters to a shell script?
And how to retrieve the parameters in the shell script?
i am a beginner.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify about your situation? Do you mean a server side shell script? What server side language are you using (as HTML alone won't cut it)?

Comment: i have a web page where u click each icon,the parameter for that icon has to passed in to a common shell file. so i dont know to pass arguments from html to shell file.. plz help!

Answer (score 0):

its not possible using only html... html is not a programming language. Are you using a programming language like PHP, or another CGI???

In php the function is [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php). If you're using a shell CGI you could directly call the shell script like in the command line

Good Luck